# Dynamics CRM Password issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have recently changed our Dynamics CRM server Administrator account password and since this change my CRM web access is no longer working I just get a basic CRM page outline with no detail and error on page in the bottom left.

I presume this will have been caused by the credential change but I can for the life of me find where to update this setting to reflect the new password in the CRM

I probably should have thought about the implications before changing the password!

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your event logs - they'll likely tell you exactly which service (likely part of IIS) is failing with an authentication error.

Comment: I have checked and there doesnt appear to be anything relating the the CRM or its services.
Regards